# May a lady take a pregnancy test on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, women, medicine, pregnancy-birth

Are there any issues with taking a pregnancy test (non-electronic) on Shabbos?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rabbi Abadi says it is permitted; [here](http://kashrut.org/forum/viewpost.asp?mid=9416):

> *Date*:   9/23/2004 7:27:00 PM
>
> *Message*:    Am I allowed to take a non-digital pregnancy test on shabbos?
>
> *Reply*:  Yes   CYA

Comment: Good maareh makom. Too bad there's no explenation.

Comment: Is that http://en.wiktionary.org/?oldid=27788589?

Comment: @msh210: No. It is Rabbi Abadi's initials.

Answer (score 10):

One issue with taking such a test is *tzovaya*, as usually the test involves chemicals in the stick changing colors by reacting to the urine. R' Ribiat, in *39 Melachos*, with regard to clinical test sticks used by diabetics to determine urine-sugar level, cites Sh'miras Shabbos K'Hilchasa (33:20), who is unsure about this (see footnotes 81-83 there), and recommends that one not urinate directly onto the stick, but rather such that the urine comes by way of *g'rama* onto the stick.

For practical ruling, though, [CYLOR](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/CYLOR).

Comment: Re "The issue with taking such a test is _tzovaya_": _the_ issue, or _an_? What about _kosev_ (many show a plus sign)? (I'm not suggesting it _is kosev_, merely that that's an issue to deal with.)

Comment: Jake, why would the case of a pregnancy test and a urine-sugar test be similar? It would seem to me (as a diabetic) that knowing if my sugar level got too high or too low, I could take immediate action that would avoid putting my life in danger by going into a diabetic shock or coma. Not sure how a 24 hour wait for a women to know if she is pregnant or not would matter. I'm not saying that a pregnancy test should or shouldn't be allowed just that I don't think you can use one to allow or not allow the other.

Comment: @Ken, I was comparing them because (although I don't know that much about it) they seem to be pretty much the same type of urine testing. The issue that one is clearly more necessary to perform immediately is a separate issue. The SSK quoted above discusses whether taking such a test is *tzovaya* in a *melacha shetzricha l'gufa* form at all. He then writes that even those who do not think it is permissible to take the urine test will allow it for *pikuach nefesh* or even *safek pikuach nefesh*. That goes without saying. The question is whether one may do so without any particular necessity to.

Comment: @Ken I was about to write jake's comment above, until I decided to read it before posting ;-) ....one thing I might add, is that those urine tests from years ago didn't provide very accurate information, and what they did tell you came hours late -- they were more for long-term adjustment of treatment, and short-term problems were treated based on how a person felt. Also, before rapid-acting insulin analogs, there really wasn't any way to treat high BG in the exact way that we do it today. Thank God for modern science!

Comment: @Ken You might find http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/76206/living-with-diabetes?referrer=1OBtgyh_32dIsjwHemAdxA2 interesting ;-)

Comment: @Ken, I am not a doctor, but one might find a reason to require a pregnancy test on Shabbat for a woman who is at risk of losing her pregnancy.  If the woman has what might be a miscarriage on Friday, checking on Shabbat that she is still pregnant may be medically relevant, and psychologically helpful.